# ItemTouchHelper make dragged item go over fragment footer

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` with an `ItemTouchHelper`.  The RecyclerView is a 2/2 grid and it has a header and footer on the page.  When the user picks up an item I want that item to be able to hover over the footer.  However, I do not want the other items in the recycler view to be able to be seen through the footer.

So first I tried adding `clipChildren` and `clipPadding` but that created a situation where the RecyclerView items were scrolling up through the footer which was a problem.  I tried adding elevation to the item and bringToFont but those never worked because the recycler view was still behind the footer, I tried adding bring to front to the recycler view itself but then once again all the items become in front of the footer again instead of just the dragged one, does anyone have any other ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by making sure your recycler view has `android:clipChildren="false"`. That way you should not need the recyclerview to be literally overlapped by the footer - it can end above the footer and still allow it's children to draw outside of bounds.

If you have a static footer you can try calling [bringToFront](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()) when you determine y axis has moved far enough that your current item intersects the footer. Then when you move back out of range or when the recyclerview scrolls at all, bring the footer back to the front. However this would be particularly error prone; a bit of a hack.

Edit:

A different approach would be to completely sever the connection between a dragged item and the recyclerview (this will take a bit of work on the drop part), the steps would roughly be:

```
- Start dragging item i
- store a reference to i.getParent() and the view index within its parent
- i.getParent().removeView(i) //detach the item from the recycler (or create clone)
- layout.addView(i) //add item onto main layout containing footer, allowing overlap

- when dropped, use the parent reference and index to reattach the item
- then work out where the item was released
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do have clipchildren = false.  The problem is, is that I want only the moving child to be over the footer, i do not want while i scroll the recycler the children as they scroll up go over the footer

Comment: As for the only calling bring to front when the item is hovering over the footer, do you mean to call bring to front on that item or bring to front on the entire recyclerview?  

The problem with doing it on the recyclerview is that the other items below the footer suddenly jump infront of it, the problem with doing it to just the moving item, is that even after calling bring to front it still stays behind the footer if the recyclerview itself is behind

Comment: Yes I understood all those points from the question - I was assuming you have a short footer the size of only one item, so that when you call bringToFront on the recycler view there wont be any items over the footer because only the dragged view will have a y-position clipping the footer. It's a fragile solution though

Comment: If you already have clipChildren false have yo made sure the RecyclerView stops *before* the footer, no overlapping? Maybe you can post your actual layout

Comment: I have tried the same but not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have a problem you need to start a separate question with the specific details and errors

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, in my custom `TouchHelperCallback` I overrided `onMove` method and ignored checking if variables source and type are the same. So when I was dragging item over header, I could put item over it.

```
@Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        //if (source.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) {
        //    return false;
        //}

        // Notify the adapter of the move
        mAdapter.onItemMove(source.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }
```

Not modified tutorial about drag drop I took from: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.jl59rui0l

Comment: I am a bit confused, I am using onMove at all?  I am using dragging but I am not moving items position.  

So my onMove just returns false.  

Why does your code help with moving items from the recyclerview over items that are not in the recyclerview?

Comment: Sorry, your problem was not specified enough.

Comment: thanks for your feedback how can I make my problem better specified?  Do you understand it now?  Maybe that is the reason for the low answer count?